# How to model galactic rotation curves?

Tags: galaxy, rotation, modeling

I have R (kpc)- distance from galactic center and v(km/s) rotational speed at that distance. I was thinking of creating a simple model comprising of 3 terms 1 for Keplerian component another for rigid body and 3rd constant, V(model)= (a/sqrt(r)) + bwr + c , where a,b,c are constants , and 'w' I am not sure how to get from this data. I also plan on using Excel's Solver feature later to minimize V(obs) - V(model). I also intend on doing all this modelling in excel instead of python or any other programming language (since I'm not very comfortable with them)
[image: Data that I was plotting and a preliminary model]

Comment: What exactly is your question? Besides that, Excel seems like the worst possible choice and I'd like to encourage you to step out of your comfort zone and learn to use real tools for data analysis.

Comment: There are tools in python which can help you to find these constants. Such as  numpy.polyfit